# Android Studio Learning - simple 2D game app; How do I get SurfaceView working Correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm learning Java and Android Studio at the same time. I'm trying to write the simplest and least amount of code possible since I'm a newbie to it all.  The app I'm trying to get going is supposed to just show a ball.png on screen but all I get is a white screen.  I'm using BlueStacks for the emulator since I'm on Windows 7 home 64 (amd) and Android Studio's emulators do not work. Here's the code.

MainActivity

```java
package com.Somechit.android2dgame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set fullscreen
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // Set No Title
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


        DrawIt gSuf = new DrawIt();

    }
 }
```

And here I'm trying to make a SurfaceView a thread also.....

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    

public class DrawIt extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
    OurView oView;
    Bitmap SBall;
    float SBallx = 0;
    float SBally=  0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        oView = new OurView(this);
        oView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        SBall = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.ball);
        setContentView(oView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        oView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        oView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent mevnt) {
        return false;
    }


    public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
        Thread OurThread = null;
        SurfaceHolder SHolder;
        boolean CanRun = false;

        public OurView(DrawIt context){
            super(context);
            SHolder = getHolder();
        }

        public void run(){
            while (CanRun){
                if (!SHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
                    continue;
                }
                Canvas OurCanvas = SHolder.lockCanvas(); //lock canvas, draw to it, then unlock it
                OurCanvas.drawARGB(255,10,10,100);
                OurCanvas.drawBitmap(SBall, SBallx, SBally, null);


                SHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(OurCanvas); // unlock canvas after updating it...
            }
        }

        public void pause(){
            CanRun = false;
            while (true){
                try{
                    OurThread.join();
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            OurThread = null;
        }

        public void resume(){
            CanRun = true;
            OurThread = new Thread(this);
            OurThread.start();
        }

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple way to create surface view and use a canvas to draw on.  The problem with most info on the internet is the fact, people are giving unecessary code...they're writing too much or including things that don't need to be included in order to show someone the simplest example form.

Here is the simplest example form of creating a surface and using canvas to draw (android 30).

```
package com.tester.android2dgame;

import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Paint;

public class MySurf extends SurfaceView {
private boolean playing = true; // this later will be used to determine if drawing can happen
Bitmap ball;
float SBallx = 0;
float SBally = 0;
char1 Ryu; // this is how you pass an instance of an object class

public MySurf(Context context){
    super(context);
    ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.ball);
    new Kanvis().start();
}

public class Kanvis extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            draw();
        }
    }

    private void draw(){
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        if (canvas != null){
            canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            canvas.drawBitmap(Ryu.Anims.get("MovDown").get(0), SBallx, SBally, paint);
            //canvas.drawBitmap(ball, SBallx, SBally, paint);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

    }


}
```

When I look at that code, it's easier to see what's going on because it doesn't have a ton of clutter.  I wish people who teach about Android Studio would do it like that; just keep it dirt simple and explain each part/arguments, etc..